# How can I monitor which routes and urls commonly requested?

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku

We have an app made from reactjs and django and it is hosted on heroku. We use axios in reactjs to make and get and post request to the django side, now are there any method in heroku that we could monitor these url requests, e.g. which url path is most commonly requested and how much are they costing at the end of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Heroku doesn't offer anything out-of-the-box, you could utilize Google Analytics to fire off an event using the library `react-ga`. You could put this in the `finally()` portion of your `fetch` call after the `then()` and `catch()` functions, this way you're able to view the number of requests attempted regardless of whether or not it was successful.